# Instant visualization for result from Fortran code

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, visualization, simulation

I found an interesting YouTube video [about instant CFD visualization](https://youtu.be/t6AYZOn-6Eg) in Fortran language.

From the video, I can see updater writes and runs Fortran code in MS Visual Studio in Windows operating system. I wonder how the visualization part is made and if not in MS Windows, but in Mac or Linux, do we still have some alternative IDE to do this kind of instant visualization directly from Fortran language?

I know some instant visualization tools like Processing can also do this, but the Java, Python or JavaScript are not as fast as Fortran to simulate and visualize flow.

Comment: I think it is just a program with some OpenGL or similar canvas, but better ask the author of the video. Of course you can write similar things without any IDE. There are GTK and OpenGL bindings available for Fortran. And you can also write the visualization in other language, from which you can call a simple visualization library, and just call the Fortran computation time-step in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

> but in Mac or Linux, do we still have some alternative IDE to do this kind of instant visualization directly from Fortran language?

Yes, you can do that with our gtk-fortran binding (GNU license): https://github.com/vmagnin/gtk-fortran/wiki

The widget GtkDrawingArea can be used to show a GdkPixbuf, which is a 1D array containing the RGB intensities of each pixel of the image. You can update this area from your computing procedure. By choosing the update rate, you can display you evolving data with very limited speed impediment.

You just need a Fortran compiler and GTK being multi-platform, you can use your program on Windows (via MSYS2), MacOS, Linux, FreeBSD...

Comment: I see you've recently added a few answers pointing to this repository, which I guess is something you develop. Please take care to read [our guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) about such promotion, and this [other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229091/253246).